# Using popPage() causes NavigatorView's page stack is empty error

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I'm very new to OnsenUI and am using v1.1.4 along with PhoneGap/Cordova. I have a lot of `ons-page` files in my project and I use `pushPage` a lot. However, I am unable to `popPage()`. I've tried to debug this on my own and I see that the pages are properly pushed onto the stack (goes from page length of 1 to 2 each time a page is pushed). However, the error message `NavigatorView's page stack is empty` always shows up whenever I try to pop a page. What could be going wrong?

Side question: Does the page length never exceed 2?

Comment: Maybe you have a navigator.resetToPage somewhere? that could possibly mess the page stack up?

Comment: I had this issue but I was including the `<ons-navigator>` on each html file - I removed it and only kept it on my index.html. It might not be what you're experiencing but worth commenting on.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigatorView's page stack is empty` also happens when you try to pop a page that is not a DOM child of the navigator.

`<ons-navigator var="appNav"></ons-navigator>` must have the child element (the page) you are trying to pop. Popping a page that does not exist will trigger the said error.

Popping Page is when you call: `appNav.popPage();`

To overcome this, one should check if the page they are trying to pop is in the ons-navigator AND ons-navigator is currently not empty.

Popping page also occurs within other ons-navigator's method calls. See those methods: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#methods-summary

Comment: Could you give more information about that and how to handle it?